# HTML button not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, jsp

I am working on a project in JavaScript, which prints out some names pulled from an XML file. I also have 3 textboxes and an update button so that if anyone types in a name in any of the textboxes, they will see the updated names when they hit the button. For example, if I originally have:

```
George
Mary
John
```

If the user types in Jane, it should change the output to:

```
Jane
Mary
John
```

However, the update button doesn't do anything when it is clicked on. Here is the code for my 3 textboxes and the button:

```
<div id = "Names">
      <input type = "text" id = "nameOne" value = "Enter a name" onClick = "if(this.value == value){this.value = '';}" />
      <input type = "text" id="nameTwo" value = "Enter a name" onClick = "if(this.value == value){this.value = '';}" />
      <input type ="text" id = "nameThree" value = "Enter a name" onClick = "if(this.value == value){this.value = '';}" />
      <input type = "button" id = "btnUpdate" value = "Update Names" onClick = "printNames()" /></div>
```

And here are the functions I am using:

```
     function getXML(){
       if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }

     else{
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","Names.xml",false);
       xmlhttp.send();
       return(xmlhttp.responseXML);
    }

function printNames() {
    var xml = getXML();
    var txt = "";
    $(xml).find("person").each(function () {
        txt += "<div>" + $(this).text() + "</div>";
    });
    $("body").append(txt);
    insertNames(name1, name2, name3);
}

function insertNames(name1, name2, name3) {
    var xmlRequest = getXML();
    var nameOneTxt = document.getElementById('nameOne').value;
    var nameTwoTxt = document.getElementById('nameTwo').value;
    var nameThreeTxt = document.getElementById('nameThree').value;
    if (nameOneTxt != null || nameTwoTxt != null || nameThreeTxt != null) {

        var x = xmlRequest.getElementsByTagName("person")[0].childNodes[0];
        x.nodeValue = nameOneTxt;
        var y = xmlRequest.getElementsByTagName("person")[0].childNodes[1];
        y.nodeValue = nameTwoTxt;
        var z = xmlRequest.getElementsByTagName("person")[0].childNodes[2];
        z.nodeValue = nameThreeTxt;
    }
    printNames();
}

printNames();
</script>
```

The printNames() function reads the names from an XML file and outputs those names using jQuery. It then calls the insertNames() function which takes in 3 parameters (for the three textboxes I have.)

The insertNames function opens an XML connection, and then gets the values for each textbox. If the textbox is not null, then that means the user input a value, in which case, a call to the XML tag is made and updates the existing content to the user input. It then calls the printNames() function which outputs the new contents.

When I test this, I get the original names output, but the update button doesn't do anything. I tried adding a print statement to the insertNames function to find that the function never runs. What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to post the `getXML()` function so we can see if it's async

Comment: Is the function actually being called?

Comment: I called `insertNames()` into `printNames()`. Then I called `printNames()` into `insertNames()` since `insertNames()` updates the xml file. So the updated names could be printed that way. I later added a `window.alert("")` to the `insertNames()` method and found that it is not executing.

Comment: by the way don't set default value as value="enter a name" on text input, use placeholder="Enter a name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is when the function is being loaded. Check this 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3R9ST/).

I have reduced your printNames call to this

```
function printNames(){
    alert(1);
}
```

If you leave it to run at default onLoad it doesn't work. If you change the load time to No wrap -in Body it works fine.

Haven't seen your code, but check where you are loading the function in relation to the onclick. The manual printNames() call at the bottom of the script will work whereas the onclick printNames() call will not.